# Responsive split screen using HTML and css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a newbie to webdesign. What is HTML and CSS for creating a simple split screen layout?

Comment: Being a "newbie to webdesign" is not sufficient reason for asking people to provide free webdesign services for you. Besides, your question is unclear. Please refer to the [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section to learn how to ask on this website.

Comment: Stating it or not doesn't change it. You should learn web design up to the point where you should be able to formulate answerable questions. And you should read the site rules.

Comment: I don't think it is unanswerable. @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu I believe it's perfectly normal for any newcomer to ask this type of question, and I don't see any wrong on the question format. Also, I don't believe nafri asked for others free service. As the matter of fact, this is a free forum, everyone volunteer their own time to answer other's question, because we all benefited from the other's help and believe in the openness of the Internet. I think its inappropriate to close this question  based on the reason you provided. Please remember that we all were newbie once.  If a newcomer can't ask question here, where they shall go?

Comment: Well, your belief contradicts the community rules, @fnjn. Besides being too broad, it's also off-topic as: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: Or, in plain English: the vast majority of questions which are not displaying any research or coding effort are not useful to future users, which is the primary criteria for providing a quality (time consuming and well documented) answer on StackOverflow. The general consensus is that low quality, low effort questions and answers should be discouraged, while promoting useful content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to this, assuming you mean a page with two columns would to have two divs like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header {width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: red;}
#col-1 {width: 50%; float: left; height: 400px; background-color: green;}
#col-2 {width: 50%; float: right; height: 400px; background-color: blue;}
/* Height can be changed but width cannot */
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>This is a header</h1></div>
<div id="col-1"><h1>This is half of a page</h1></div>
<div id="col-2"><h1>This is another half of a page</h1></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a code pen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqvyYp?editors=1000

*Since this using percentages for width, this would be responsive

Comment: I answered his question and he said it worked, so that doesn't mean that people should down vote my answer since he didn't word it that well.

Comment: she*. It has solved my problem to some extent. I don't why are you getting down votes. Here's a +1 from me. cheers

Comment: Sorry, I called you a he, you just don't know sometimes, and thank you for up voting my answer.  In my experience with this website you will find that many people on it will be sour to you.

Comment: Haha true. You'll get more downvotes if you'll say something against them. @JR Kibbey